# How can I upload and download files in the OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR?

Tags: ssh, terminal, openshift

I'm pretty new to SSH and such, so I'm not sure how to do this.  I can `ssh` into the server pretty easy:

```
ssh uuid@appname-domain.rhcloud.com
```

and `cd` into the data directory:

```
cd app-root/data
```

But I'm not sure where to go from there.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use Winscp for windows. Here is post about the subject from openshift.

https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/copying-files-to-server

Answer (score 0):

If you have an scp command line utility installed, you can use the rhc scp command